# I am working on proving or disproving $\cos^5(x)-\sin^5(x)=\cos(5x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

True or false? $$\cos^5(x)-\sin^5(x)=\cos(5x)$$ for all real x.
I have no idea how to prove or disprove this. I tried to expand $\cos(5x)$ using double angle formula but I wasn't sure how to go from that to $$\cos^5(x)-\sin^5(x)$$

Comment: If you are interested in what $\cos(5x)$ **is** equal to, expand both sides of $e^{(5x)i} = (e^{xi})^5$ using Euler's equation $e^{ti} = \cos(t) + i \sin(t)$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$x=\dfrac{\pi}{4} \implies \cos^5 x-\sin^5 x=0 \neq\cos \dfrac{5\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

Pick values of $x$ where $\cos 5x=1$.  Does $\cos^5x-\sin^5x=1$?

Comment: You beat me by < 1 minute!

Answer (score 0):

It is false. Quick counterexample: Note that, at $x=\frac{\pi}{5}$, we have $ \cos (5x) = -1 $, but clearly${}^\dagger$, $ \cos^5 \left( \frac {\pi}{5} \right) - \sin^5 \left( \frac {\pi}{5} \right) \ne 1 $. $\Box$

---

${}^\dagger$ It is clear that, since $ \frac {\pi}{5} $ is acute, $ 0 < \cos^5 \left( \frac {\pi}{5} \right), \sin^5 \left( \frac {\pi}{5} \right) < 1 $. Hence, $$ \cos^5 \left( \frac {\pi}{5} \right) - \sin^5 \left( \frac {\pi}{5} \right) < 1. $$This is how we get that it is not equal to $1$.

Comment: That is "clearly" without any calculation?

Comment: @SuzuHirose - Yes, it is clear without doing calculations. I have clarified in my post.

Comment: I think you mean $\pi/5$ is acute.

Comment: @ganbustein - Yes, thanks.